# How to post a follow-up question?

Tags: discussion, faq, site-policy, asking-questions, iterative-review

Sometimes I stumble upon follow-up questions, where code is being posted again after having gone through a review (or two).

Examples of possible sets of follow up questions:

- [Find missing numbers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35902/find-a-missing-numbers-single-missing-number-and-two-missing-numbers-from-cons) - [Find even more missing numbers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36031/find-two-missing-elements-from-a-sorted-array-in-given-range) - [Even more missing numbers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36117/find-missing-numbers-in-a-range-when-a-sorted-array-with-two-elements-with-rang)
- [Binary search tree](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31994/creating-a-binary-search-tree) - [Another binary search tree](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31998/create-a-binary-tree-code-review-request)

Related meta questions:

- https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210/how-are-reposts-handled-on-code-review
- https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/iterative-code-reviews-how-can-they-happen-successfully
- [What is the best way to exchange a dialogue following a code review?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/562/what-is-the-best-way-to-exchange-a-dialogue-following-a-code-review)

**How should a follow-up question be posted properly?**

**How to deal with follow-up questions?**

Comment: Is is just co-incidence that all these questions are from the same user? Are there other examples?

Comment: @rolfl I believe there are more examples but I haven't kept links to them. When the data explorer works for Code Review, perhaps a query or two can help in finding such questions.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I think that such question should **clearly state** that it is a **follow-up question to a previously asked question.**

A **good** follow-up question should include, in my opinion:

- **Which** question it is a follow-up to
- **What** changes has been made in the code since last question
- **Why** a new review is being asked for

If a question does not include (at least some of) these things, I think that we should close it as a duplicate (or at least give it a down-vote)

There are also [some things you should note if you are posting several follow-ups](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6050/31562)

In addition to the above, **each follow-up question should be a good question also by itself.**

Comment: Yes I think it's a valid follow up question from same user if he/she learned from the previous review and improved his/her code accordingly.

Comment: @doug65536 I am sorry that you feel that way because you haven't got any answers in the last 24 hours on your follow-up question. I believe that the fact that some questions get little attention is not related to whether or not it was a follow-up post. You can try [improving the quality of your question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562), ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) if anyone can look at your question, or add a bounty to your question.

Comment: @SimonForsberg Yeah, my bad. I realized that I had mis-tagged the question as C++14, probably watched by a lot fewer users watching than C++. Nothing in the question was particularly C++14 related. It had a very low "views" count though, which misled me to believe that it was being ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Everything that [Simon wrote](/a/1066/75307).  Additionally, you can help readers of the original question find your improved version:

- Include a *link* to the original question.  This will ensure that each question appears in the other one's Linked Questions list (in the right-hand column, for the current default presentation).
- *Accept* one of the answers to the original question.  This is a strong hint that you believe that version has been sufficiently reviewed now.

Be prepared for a follow-up review to take longer: the obvious deficiencies having been addressed, reviewers need to spend longer digging further below the surface to find improvements to suggest.  And those who reviewed version 1 may intentionally hold back before answering, to allow other reviewers to give different perspectives.