# Specifying that a question is still under construction

Tags: discussion

Since modifying code is not allowed after an answer has been received, can a user comment on a question he/she just posted to state that the question is under construction, therefore postponing fast answers?

**Example Scenario**

1. User posts a question (it is on topic).
2. After reading it again he/she realize something is missing/wrong.
3. It might take a while to update the question.
4. Posts a comment saying **"Wait! my question is under construction"**

Is such behavior allowed, or should the user delete and post it again?

**Related**

[About answer-invalidating edits](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2375/about-answer-invalidating-edits)

Comment: You could type up a question in something like [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/) (which seems pretty neat) and copy it over when it's ready.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way to specify that your question was pre-emptively posted and still under construction would be to delete it.

When you delete a question, you can still edit it, and then undelete it once you're done.  Deleting the question will completely prevent anyone from posting an answer that your edit would invalidate.

---

As to leaving a comment... you could if you wanted to I suppose.  But it's not particularly reasonable for this comment to be binding whatsoever.  If you were to post this comment, then I posted an answer, I think we'd still rollback an edit after my answer.

The trouble is, what happens when you edited that comment in after I was already working on my answer?  I may not even see that you edited this comment in until after I posted my answer and the page completely refreshed.

Comment: You are correct. So simply, posting under construction comment is not allowed. isn't it ?

Comment: That seems to have changed recently. I have a recently deleted question and the [edit] button is disabled; if I wanted to edit it, I'd have to undelete it... which defeats the purpose. Also if an answer is being written, answerer will only know they can't post their answer... when they're done and click the [Post Your Answer] button. So yeah they can't post it... but if they started writing it up and spend 2 hours on it only to be told that *deleted posts cannot be answered*.. which is a bit infuriating.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it'd be disallowed.  It certainly wouldn't be binding.  If you added that comment, then I added an answer, we'd still rollback any edit you made after my answer.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Then the solution would be to delete the current answer and post a new one.  And the lesson would be to not post questions that aren't ready yet.

Comment: @nhgrif thanks, That comment clarifies it, please add it to the answer.