# Ability to edit self-deleted questions

Tags: feature-request, editing, deleted-questions

I understand that preventing edits on deleted *answers* can help defeat FGITW (*Fastest Gun In The West*) problems on other sites (or here?), but it seems deleted *questions* cannot be edited either.

This creates a problem with questions that were posted too fast and that [need to be edited](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2423/23788) while preventing answers that would be invalidated by such edits.

Is it just me or this is a new behavior in the software? Please bring back the ability to edit self-deleted *questions*!

Comment: Note: posted from phone, will edit later, add related meta post links and all.

Comment: I don't know what "FTGITW" is... but I was able to edit a deleted answer on [so] yesterday...

Comment: Related: [Edit a self-deleted question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213632/edit-a-self-deleted-question) (and read the comments)

Comment: @rolfl right. So the solution is to leave it deleted and post another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Undeleting a question does not 'bump' it in the system, which is by design, because deleting, and undeleting a question should not be a way to 'bump' your question.

Similarly, editing a deleted question, and then undeleting it, would allow for users to completely change their question, and then, because the undelete would not bump the question, it is unlikely that the revised question would be significantly 'reviewed'. It would be a way for people to 'game' the system by introducing content that may be harmful.

So, you can't bump a question by undeleting it, and as a result, you cannot edit a question when you deleted it.

The solution is either:

1. create a new question with the new content.
2. undelete the question (no bump), then edit it, with bump.

In your case, I recommend editing the new content in a separate editor, then undeleting, and editing the new content in immediately.

The reason for this suggestion is that leaving your question deleted will count negatively toward the 'soctratic' badges.