# Versioning code and visualizing diffs in code review

Tags: feature-request, iterative-review

Based on the [rules for editing code under review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c), I would like to recommend this feature.

The goal of code review is to improve my submitted code, and for others to learn from the improved code - I would like to provide an updated version back to the community.

I could do this by simply editing the original post but that causes us to lose the original code in question and the community recommendations no longer have the right context (not to mention that is not allowed on the site - and rightly so).

I could post the updated code back as an answer to the post or as a new question but, imo, that gets too noisy and difficult to track.

I would like to see something like tabs or links at the top of each code block that would allow me to track and post various versions of the code in order to show how it has changed based on the reviewers feedback - showing how the code evolved overtime.  I think this would provide a lot of insight and very useful.  Each 'version' should also allow me to credit specific reviews who helped refactor the code.

Another alternative (actually should be in addition to above idea) is a link within the code that pops up when there are various diffs for a section of code.

Comment: I agree that the system we have is not perfect, I am not sure how/if we can influence the SE developers to create susch a thing though, it will be a 'hard sell' to make a new feature for Code Review only. Can you think of any other sites that may benefit?

Comment: I would like the ability to show a diff in a review - even if it's a manual way of highlighting lines red and green - to make suggested changes clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought: Assuming if we solve the 'question' side of identifying multiple iterations of a code review, how should answers be referenced back to the particular iteration then? By an anchor link to the particular iteration?

Comment: And this is how the cookie crumbles... I think it's best to keep it simple, I think the way we're handling it now is the best way to go about it - no versioning on the OP/Question automatically makes all answers in sync with the same version; the "perfect" post-review code can be posted in a new question - if it *is* perfect then reviews/answers should say so. Basically 1 version of the code == 1 CR question == 1 round of reviews.