# What to do with Code Only Answer in Low Quality Queue

Tags: discussion, review

The only options currently are

- Looks OK
- Edit
- Delete
- Skip

But when you have a code only answer,

- It isn't Okay
- There isn't anything to edit really
- Deleting a good start to a review seems like a bad idea
- Skipping the review doesn't help anyone

What should be done when the code looks like an improvement, but there is no explanation of why the code would be better written like the code provided?

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/59778
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/59770

Comment: The way I see it would be : leave a comment and vote-to-delete after a period of 2day if nothing was done, but it's not achievable from the queue.

Comment: @Marc-Andre, these ones were already commented on when I saw them in the queue. I agree with you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Deleting a good start to a review seems like a bad idea

Indeed. But you don't *delete* the post, you **vote** to delete it. Just do it. And downvote.

---

You could also come across one such answer outside the review queues. Often, this results in [correct] NAA flags. Let's be clear: **a code dump is not a review**, and therefore not an acceptable answer.

However if the post already has a mod notice, I'll dismiss an NAA flag, because short of outright mod-deleting the post (which can then only be un-deleted by a moderator), there's not much else to do for a moderator.

The correct course of action should be to **downvote** until the score is low enough to **vote to delete**, and then vote to delete - in an ideal world moderators wouldn't even need to get involved with those, [Trusted Users](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (20K+) should be able to handle it.

Of course, if nobody did before, **comment** and make sure the author gets a chance to edit and improve their answer before it gets nuked from orbit.

Comment: Actually... reality is, more often than not, NAA flags get through and the answer gets mod-deleted after a while anyway.

Comment: @downvoter please feel free to comment about how can this answer be improved, or answer yourself.

Comment: To the user have a notification when the community or a mod delete his answer ? I've never been on that side of the situation.

Comment: @Marc-Andre no notification (that's why comments matter), but they can see their deleted post, and who deleted it... I think.

Comment: I think the most important thing is the **downvote and comment**. I personally don't like deleting them just because it is a code-dump (except in some cases). Another user might come in and edit, or it might add some value to someone despite being a code dump.