# What should I do if someone continues to edit the question after being told to stop?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answer-invalidation

The particular rule is "[What you can and cannot do after receiving answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)."  As I understand it, when we see someone edit code after receiving an answer, we should revert the edit and post a comment linking to that Meta answer.  I did that on [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67746/simple-shell-in-c), and the asker has since added at least one more edit.

Should I revert again?  Vote to close?  Something else?

In this particular case, I flagged for moderator attention.  Is that what I should always do?

Answer (score 13):

Flagging it for moderator attention was justified.  Thanks for your vigilance and for doing your part to keep the review process fair.

I've reminded the user of the rule and closed the question as "Unclear what you are asking."  If the author of the question reverts it to a state that it was in before the first answer was posted, we may consider reopening it.

Answer (score 12):

As @200_success has mentioned, flagging was justified.  Had you reverted again, then the OP may have done the same, starting a *rollback war*.  Never try to engage in a rollback war.  If one ever occurs, whether or not you're involved, wait for a moderator to lock the post, preventing further edits.

Comment: Locking the post seems like the best solution.