# Authors 'final result' post showing the 'final result' after the answer/corrections/suggestions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, iterative-review

**The case**: Somebody posts code for review then follows up with all the analysis and some of the answers is accepted.

**The suggestion**: Some kind of finalization post by the dev who is asking the question which is the corrected/final implementation according to all proper suggestions and analysis.

**Why**: To get not only the review/analysis but to get to the final version. Sometimes the analysis points out to several aspects of the code which need to be updated without explicitly writing the whole code. This is ok since the analysis is good but the dev asking the question needs to do his homework and to update his code on his own.

By providing the final result in separate post we have

1. Clean/final result
2. Clean "story" from beginning to end
3. The satisfaction of the analysis provider that the recipient got it right and implemented it right too

Is not this the standard path of a code review in a software workshop/company?

Initial code/review post -> analysis -> correction/update -> final code

What do you think?

Comment: You mean something that's [already in place](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765/22222)?

Comment: @Jamal - nope. If I do that I will accept my own answer which is not correct because I am not writing an answer but an update. The "answer" mark is deserved by the author of the analysis and not by the consumer - the dev asking the question. If I post my own answer after receiving the the analysis from other person and mark mine as the answer looks like ungrateful for the guys that gave me the proper analysis.

Comment: So, are you referring to a new change in infrastructure, beyond just the current answering system?

Comment: I do not imply such deep change. Probably some kind of flag saying "Hey guys! Thanks for the nice answer. Here is the final version with your updates. So if anybody comes across such problem - here is the final result from start to end"

Comment: I still don't understand this suggestion.  A "flag" doesn't seem to fit here because they're solely for moderation.  As for thanking others, that's what upvotes and checkmarks are for.  Other than that, it still looks like your suggests are similar to what's already in place.

Comment: This is occasionally done today. Typically in the form of a community wiki answer.

Comment: @Jamal, It really is the same as the one you pointed out in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to answer your own question with the final implementation. Noting which answers helped you achieve your final result is acceptable, but sweeping statements like

> after looking at all the answers given, this is my final implementation

are fine as well.

Explicitly thanking people in such answers is considered [non-SE compliant fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778/1014587).

As for which answer to mark, the usual advice applies. Mark the answer you considered the most helpful to you. Your own answer may be the final implementation, but it wasn't the most helpful to you.

Code Review isn't Stack Overflow. On Stack Overflow, self-answering questions are a good thing. Although it's still acceptable here, it's not recommended in most cases for the reason given above.

If you're going to write an answer for your own question, keep point 3 of [this answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/52915) in mind.

Comment: This is it. Thanks.

Comment: Also note, that an "answer" consisting of a code dump with the "final code" (...is code ever "final"??) **will** be downvoted and flagged as "not an answer" - please shape your selfie in the form of a review, as if you were reviewing your own code (which you can always do anyway); explain why changes are made (and/or link to answers that do). This site isn't about the "final code" after all; it's about *understanding* how code can be improved. Just dumping the improved code as an answer saying "thanks all, this is how it looks now" provides no value whatsoever.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I've added the link already provided by Jamal for completeness sake.