# Can I ask the same question with a different language?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I am wondering if it would be bad to ask for the same code review, just under a different language.

For example:

*Hypothetically* I post a question asking for a code review of my Ruby "Hello World" program, but then, I create a C# "Hello World" program, and would like insight as well. Since they are different languages with different run times, it would not seem that it would be too bad.

This of course is an oversimplified example and I would be posting about small web services. Would there be a problem with this?

Comment: related: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A36366+%5Bfizzbuzz%5D+is%3Aq

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think there would be a problem with this.  In fact, I'm sure several people have posted [fizzbuzz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz) in 2 or more languages.

However... you'll realize that lots of comments you can receive are actually language agnostic.  I'd recommend that you allow a bit of time between posting these questions and make sure you take into account any reviews you received on the previous question (the language agnostic points).

Comment: lol. I think it's funny that we independently thought of [tag:fizzbuzz]

Comment: Really?  I'm surprised only two of us posted answers mentioning it.

Answer (score 8):

I will add to the chorus of "yes, it's OK" answers but want to draw your attention to the more personal nature of Code Review - not only can you present two questions with the same problem, solved in different languages, but you can even post two questions with the same problem in the ***same*** language.

Specifically, on Code Review you are encouraged to take the suggestions given in one answer, apply as much as you feel necessary to your code, add your own modifications and then present the revised code ***again*** for review. Subsequent reviews can confirm your changes made sense, and if the changes make other problems more apparent, you may get further insights or suggestions.

This "follow on" nature is [described well in this editing-related meta post.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c)

So, take what you learn in one place, apply it again, or differently in another, and post the result or review.... rinse, and repeat.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like a great plan. Duplicates are kind of a funny thing here. They don't really exist (unless they really are *exact* duplicates). I've lost count of the [fizzbuzz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz) questions and there are really only 4 or 5 different implementations of that one.

Go for it. You're good.

Comment: There are 84 [tag:fizzbuzz] questions to this date. Yeah, really.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I think you mean that there are _fizz_ fizzbuzz questions to date.