# Increase character limit to 75k

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Let's increase the character limit to, say, 75 000 characters. 65 000 is not enough. I face that problem a second time now. I have to exclude some code and instead store it elsewhere and provide a link. Not perfect

Answer (score 3):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

I will collect the (now removed) comments in this answer, since I agree with them all. The last one is my own. In short, I don't see any support for it.

You state:

> I have to exclude some code and instead store it elsewhere and provide a link.

Please read our [FAQ - Can I put my code on a third party site and link to the site in my question?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1308/52915):

The code to be reviewed must be present in the question. **Code behind links is considered non-reviewable**. If your code does not fit the character limit, you can split it up and/or you may add a link to a site where more of your code can be seen, but don't expect anyone here to review it.

---

> To be honest, questions of 65000 characters or more don't always get answered. You made a point in your other [meta question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10922/can-we-make-some-in-built-git-repository) that copying and pasting large questions are tedious, this is also true of reviewing (answering) large questions. Not all of my questions have been answered because they are too large. I have had problems with the limit on 2 or 3 questions, I broke the question into multiple posts. –
> [pacmaninbw](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/79357/pacmaninbw) Dec 30, 2023 at 16:11

> I don't think you have anything to gain from posting more than 65k characters. You're just falling into a trap where your question will never be answered. –
> [Peilonrayz](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42401/peilonrayz) Dec 30, 2023 at 16:15
>
> "[people tend to avoid time-consuming things if they are not rewarding enough](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10922#comment21693_10922)" - you. Following your own logic, which question are people going to gravitate towards answering; one with 100k characters vs one with 500 characters? Cloning repositories is relatively insignificant compared to reading and understanding such a large code base. – [Peilonrayz](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42401/peilonrayz) Dec 30, 2023 at 17:29
>
> I recently wrote an answer on [possible ways to improve the likelihood of getting answers on multiple questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10904). The problem is complicated. We also have a few other guides on Meta (which I don't have time to search for) on how to write better questions. – [Peilonrayz](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42401/peilonrayz) Dec 30, 2023 at 17:40

> Larger projects are much harder to review and to get reviewed than small projects. That was already so when the character limit was 30k. When it was raised to 65536 back in 2015, that problem did not go away. Moving the limit further up will not make the projects easier to review. – [Mast](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast) Dec 30, 2023 at 17:42