# "Obsolete" meta posts: should we delete them?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta

Comments on an answer given [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6065/23788) suggest plain deleting the meta questions we marked as "obsolete".

These are old posts about site policy, that have been superseded by newer & better posts.

I don't think it's a bad idea to delete them, but I would like some input from the community before <s>rewriting history</s> proceeding.

How valuable is it to keep those around?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes. Delete them.

Deletes are visible to users with enough rep, and they just confuse things right now.

The only reason someone may want to see these posts is to track the history of a particular policy. I recommend adding links to the deleted posts in the current version to make that trail more obvious....

Answer (score 1):

**NO**

Whilst the information they contain has been entirely superseded, they are a part of our site history and I think they should be kept as a matter of record.

What problem are they causing that would justify deleting them completely?

Or, to put it another way: What, exactly, do we gain from deleting them?

Comment: confusion, or rather clarity :)

Comment: *["The change in the title was because people would search for "invalidation", or "iterative", and then paste a link to the post in a comment when some user edited their question and invalidated answers. Locking would not solve that common problem from a while ago."* – rolfl](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6065/usage-of-obsolete-modifier-in-the-title-on-cr-meta#comment13698_6066)

Comment: Deletion is a more permanent solution than oddly naming them with a tag.

Answer (score -3):

### No. Merge them

The posts which invalidate them are duplicates.
It would take a bit of work (and required mod intervention to do the merge).
But Merging them keeps all the information, (edits will be needed) in one place.

(Just to provide a third option. Not 100% I think this is a good idea)

Comment: More likely to cloud "history" and would indeed require a lot of editing to make for a clean merge. Plus you might find that answers have different vote counts, making the older answer the "better" answer...