# How can I post updates/implementation of changes after a code review?

Tags: discussion, iterative-review

I have asked for a code review in a post and received nice feedback. I would now like to implement the suggestions, and possibly get new feedback ("Yes, that was the problem, good fix" or "No, dude, you got it all wrong because...").

Can you please tell me what I should do, so that the person who bothered to answer the original question would be notified about this? Should I edit the original question? Should I post the update as an answer or what?

Answer (score 5):

You will find the answer to most of you questions in this [almost duplicate discussion](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c).

> Should I edit the original question, should I post the update as an answer or what?

Never, ever edit the code in the original question. See the discussion I linked above for more details.

> Can you please tell me what should I do, so that the person who bothered to answer the original question would be notified about this?

Add a comment on their answers, with a link to your new post.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I edit the original question, should I post the update as an answer or what?

Editing the original question after you have received answers to show updated code **isn't allowed by our site policy**, because this would invalidate given answers and any future answerer wouldn't know which code they should review.

You have different options based on what you want to get out of it.

- If you just want to show the updated code you could add it as an answer to your question **but** it has to be in a code review form.
- if you want feedback on the updated code you should post a follow up question which should contain a link to the original question. Also adding a link to the follow up question in the original question will be good.

See also: [For an iterative review, is it okay to edit my own question to include revised code?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c?rq=1)