# Do I edit my question based on answers?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, iterative-review

A very simple question, but I haven't seen whether this is acceptable behaviour here. I do see mention of 'iterative' code reviews, which I assume refers to "post, receive answer(s), edit, answers updated" type questions.

Apologies if this is already explained somewhere.

Comment: No. [Here's some more info](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765/42401), where it might answer your question in the **In addition...** header.

Answer (score 1):

No, because editing the question by integrating answers would invalidate the answers.

Answer (score 1):

> I do see mention of 'iterative' code reviews, which I assume refers to "post, receive answer(s), edit, answers updated" type questions.

An iterative review is multiple questions on the same problem.  Each code modification is a new question with new answers.

There is more information under the [link](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/42401) that @JoeWallis posted.