# Could Code Review also serve as a code repository?

Tags: discussion, iterative-review

The main purpose of Code Review is for asking questions and providing answers. But can we also use Code Review as a code repository because it will provide more search engine visibility. I have submitted [this code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135667/fetching-specific-foreign-exchange-rates-from-fixer-using-curl-and-jsconcpp-in-c?noredirect=1#comment255304_135667) for review and also got an answer for it. Upon suggestion, I also improved my code and want to share it in the same question. But re-editing the code is discouraged as per [this SE post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c).

After accepting an answer, an we re-edit the question and add new information and code without changing any previous content or code?

This is what I want:

```
Q:Fetching specific foreign exchange rates from fixer using curl and jsconcpp in C++
<content>
<code>
//(future edits)//
EDIT 1:
<content>
<code>
EDIT 2:
<content>
<code>
EDIT 3..etc.
```

Can we do that?

Comment: That's actually mentioned in the linked question as quoted: *You also **should not append your revised code to the question.***

Comment: Code repositories provide other features not included here. Like version control. Easy sharing (forking). Easy integration of contributers code (pull requests). Issue tracking. Branching. etc.... I just use github account it's free and you can have unlimited private projects.  Also code review provides integration with github for badges: `[![Code Review](http://www.zomis.net/codereview/shield/?qid=<questionID>)](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/<questionID>/<userID>)` See:  https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 6):

## No (kinda)

It's not okay to edit revisions of code into questions, because someone's review for revision 1 will be irrelevant for future revisions. This is called answer invalidation, and is something we do not like here at all.

With that in mind, you're welcome to post new questions with the updated code. This is called an iterative review and it happens all the time.

As for *code repository*, it seems like you're trying to leverage Stack Exchange's SEO to promote your product. That's all good and well, but repositories are for continuous development, not reviewing a *specific* bit of code. Trying to "*host*" such a repo here is not okay, that goes toward the answer invalidation I mentioned before. The better alternative is to link to your GitHub project in the post (which happens all the time).