# What to do with a post that feels like a blog entry?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, flagging

I've been following [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229477/string-whitespaces) pretty closely, reading comments and everything because the "reasoning part" seemed... blog-ish.

By reading [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/229478/40395) and the comments under it + the way the reasoning is worded, it seems like the author wrote this question only to write the reasoning part, that has mostly nothing to do with the code to be reviewed itself and looks like a political speech regarding software development (the kind of thing I'd expect to read on a Medium post).

I've also flagged [the author's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/229487/40395) as Not An Answer, because, let's be honest, it's not one. But my flag was disputed, I would like to know, if possible, what were the justifications behind this.

I still think the post has value, as in "There's code to be reviewed and the reviews are good" (I'm still uncertain as to if the OP was looking for a review at all, but let's assume good faith), but the main question is : **Should something be done about the "reasoning" part, that brings no value to the post? Should it be edited out?** On the side, I'm wondering why the answer I linked was flagged as "Looks OK", but it's less important I believe.

I just think that if posts like this were to get more frequent, Code Review would change for the worse.

Comment: regarding the flag: It was disputed by the Community-user after the "low quality" review item got 2 "Looks OK" and 2 "Recommend Deletion" votes

Comment: Your "question" link points to the answer.

Comment: @JL2210 Considering answer and question are by the same author, I suspect he means the combination. Although I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: @JL2210 I fixed it

Comment: What exactly is your question? It reads like you just want to know why your flag has been disputed.

Comment: @Heslacher Yeah I guess it's more of a 2 way question, let me rephrase that.

Answer (score 3):

> Should something be done about the "reasoning" part, that brings no
>   value to the post? Should it be edited out?

IMO voting is the way to go here.
Editing out the reasoning part won't make the question any better. If I look at the question above the reasoning part I don't see a good question. It reads more like an answer to a question.

Answer (score 3):

The question is for questions, not for responding to answers. It's sufficiently simple and clear-cut that I have, as Wikipedia puts it, *be[en] bold* and rolled back to a version of the question which was pretty much just question. (I was tempted to roll back to version 1, but I thought that might be overdoing it).

On the more general subject of how to respond to answers, see [Respond to an answer?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7333/1402)