# Add question editing recommendations to Community Tour

Tags: feature-request, help-center, new-users

After receiving some good feedback on my [first question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179293/general-fizzbuzz-in-scala), I decided to edit my question to incorporate the advice with the idea to create a copy-pasteable "final version" for future visitors. However, I learned from comments that such edits are not recommended based on [this Meta discussion](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/152372).

It might be helpful to new users to explicitly mention that editing your question to address feedback is discouraged in the community tour.

Answer (score 6):

*A lot* of things would be helpful to new users to explicitly mention in the tour... the whole entire [*Help Center*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) would be helpful!

The thing about answer-invalidating edits isn't specific to Code Review in any way though: Stack Exchange being a Q&A concept (as opposed to a *discussion forum* concept), *as described in the tour*, rather implicitly implies that editing answered questions to turn them into impossible-to-follow discussions, is frowned upon.

The specific bit about answer-invalidating edits can be found on [/help/someone-answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Except some site-specific images, the tour is essentially the same for all SE sites, as it's more about the *mechanics* of how Stack Exchange works, than it is about the site-specific rules you can find in the help center.

That said, mucho kudos for taking the tour!

Comment: I still think this should be explicitly mentioned in either [ask] or the tour. Preferably in large font. Sure, it's somewhere in the help center, but do we really want to raise the entry barrier from "went through this quick, interesting-to-watch thing" to "read every single wall of text in the help center"?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I get that, but if [ask] becomes "everything you need to know about this site", it's no longer about "how to ask".

Comment: There's a difference between "everything you need to know about this site" and "the most important things to know about this site". One would be basically impossible to maintain; the other just includes the results of very important, non-intuitive things like, say, not updating the code. On SO it might be obvious, but on CR it seems to make sense that you'd update your code with the suggested fixes to get another round of reviews on it. It's important enough, and non-obvious enough, that it should be explicitly stated.