# Encouraging the community to edit the question to maintain a list of external resources

Tags: support, specific-question, site-policy, roll-back

I have requested and successfully received a [nice review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/241807/37449) about a piece of code which relies on a pool of third part services.

Since the code was nicely welcomed with some upvotes I thought that it might be useful to other people in the future and that it would be nice to keep the pool of services updated with contributions from the community.

I therefore edited my question to facilitate this process. However another user [edited](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/241807/revisions) my question back commenting:

> "Please do not recommend continuously editing the question just to
>   update a list of external resources."

I understand that this is not the primary scope of codereview, but so many times I have incurred in very old and outdated Q/A that are polluting my google searches. What is wrong in maintaining the code in a question or answer fully functional and useful? And what is wrong having the community helping the process either by edits or comments?

Note that I am not angered towards the edit, neither I am interested in polemics, I just want to better understand the rationale in order to be more proficient in the future. Also my original idea was to contact the editor privately via chat, but I have not been able to.

Comment: "What is wrong in maintaining the code in a question or answer fully functional and useful?" It's a lot of work, nobody will oversee the process and we already have a participation problem (as in, more work than participants to spread the work over). I was the editor and I practically live in [The 2nd Monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor). You can always contact me and some of the other users there, as noted in my profile. If you prefer private chat, I can create a pseudo-private chat on request. But I don't mind discussing this in The 2nd.

Comment: For the record, I understand the sentiment. But the extra work and potential problems don't outweigh the benefit. Partially related is our [policy to disallow invalidating code edits](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1763/52915).

Comment: @Mast The target of my encouragement was the occasional user who googled out the question, found it useful for their project and had a couple of new services to share. That's it, I had absolutely no intention to redirect the work of the community. I do not believe that such an encouragement could influence how people choose to spend their time online...

Comment: ...and for this case I do not think that "code edit" is the appropriate label. The code remains the same in all its shape and functionalities, only the content of a list is being updated. Not that I care so much or that I want to convince you. We can perfectly agree to disagree.

Answer (score 6):

We don't have the tools to help you with your request. If you want to keep the list updated, then creating a GitHub, SourceForge or BitBucket repository will be better equipped for that. Anyone with an account can create a PR and if you set the permissions up, you can get it so  *anyone* can update the list without a PR. You also get additional features such as issues, a readme that isn't a question and integration with many CI tools.

If you want to make the repository and edit your post to include a link to it then that's fine. However keeping the most up-to-date version of your code in the question goes against site policy and is not a great use of anyone's time.

Comment: I am not asking the community to redirect their work to maintain my code. I am encouraging anyone profiting from it and possibly knowing additional services, to just share them. Personally I would upvote any single answer that propose even a single link to an additional service, but I feel that many would be reluctant in posting such answers.

Comment: @DarioP The activity you wish to encourage would be better served on the sites I mentioned in my answer. Others can add 'issues' or 'pull requests' to _your_ repository to improve your solution.

Comment: For such a silly task as maintaining a list of links, versioning tools seem an overkill to me. Plus they require my active intervention, which means that I can be a bottleneck in spreading the improvements. An open collaborative wiki-style space seems much more appropriate... mmmh maybe this is a decent business idea!

Comment: @DarioP Again that concern was mentioned in the answer. I also provided a solution.