# Are Code Golf King-of-the-Hill controller programs allowed here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am in the process of writing a KOTH challenge for Code Golf (it's on the meta sandbox), and like for all KOTH challenges I need to write some code to pit everyone's bot against each other. I've done this but before my question goes live, I need people to review my code so that users can understand how to use it, how to make their bot, what methods are available to them, etc. It might be important to note that my code has about three files which are too long to paste, but I could easily put them onto GitHub or Google Drive.

Answer (score 19):

If you have code that implements real functionality, and it's your code, and it works, then the code is on-topic for review, regardless of what the purpose of the code is, with some exceptions:

1. the code you want reviewed has to be included in the question itself (links to supporting code on off-site systems like github are OK for background use only - code on those systems will not be reviewed.
2. the objective of the review is to provide suggestions on how to make your code "better". Golfing the code is off-topic, but I don't believe that is your objective.
3. you should be prepared to get feedback on any and all aspects of your code.

If your code is too large, then consider extracting those parts that are most critical for your task.

Also, I strongly recommend you read: [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions)

Comment: I want to ask about how I set up classes and subclasses in my program and whether I should do it better, but that would require 2 files no?

Comment: If your code is not written yet, or you don't know how to do it, then it is not ready for a code review. You'd be looking for team-programming for that, and there's no site on SE that does that.

Comment: I have it written, and I've already used a specific class hierarchy system but I am not sure if it is optimal, and am ready to change it if that is better practice

Comment: It sounds like your question should be fine. Go ahead and ask it.