# Little applet for elo rating system

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have written a bit of Python code with Tkinter to make a small applet to allow people to enter game scores and keep track of their rating (using the elo rating system).

I have an initial meta-question for using this site: Can I just post the entire code here for review?  Or is that not how it's done?  I have specific improvements etc. that I want to make, of course, but I'm initially trying to ensure that I don't misuse Code Review, as I have never posted here before.

Comment: Please see this meta post: [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Welcome to CR! First things first, questions *about* the site belong on meta - every Stack Exchange site has a meta counterpart. So I've migrated your question over here.

Feel free to browse some of the site's top-voted questions - you'll find they mostly share a number of common points:

- they provide sufficient plain-English context so that reviewers can know what the code is doing without having to figure it out from the code itself.
- they have an interesting title that hints at what the code is doing (not at what OP wants out of a review).
- they all include the code to be reviewed. All of it, and with sufficient contextual code so reviewers don't need to make assumptions or guesses about such function or such variable.

As long as your post doesn't exceed the 30K characters limit imposed by the Stack Exchange system, you're good to go.

See [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) (and/or browse the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag on this meta site) for more information.

Comment: So the 30K limitation is slightly too tight for me.  My code is probably around 45K.  I could obviously break it up, but that would appear to defeat the point.  What would you suggest for slightly longer bits of code that you want to be made public in case anyone wants to see it, and have suggestions made on it?

Comment: @DrXorile Consider [tag:rubberduck] - it's an entire project being reviewed there, over 2K commits in, with dozens of thousands of lines of code. Each question is focused on a [relatively] small/specialized aspect of the project, and all make good CR questions. I suggest you ask a number of "themed" questions, spanning anywhere between a single method and a small set of related classes, ideally a number of days apart so you can apply any applicable changes to the rest of your code as reviews come in (only 1 question/day counts toward the [socratic] badge!) - and link to the repo in each post.

Comment: @DrXorile, Code Review has a larger post length limit than other SE sites: [65K characters, apparently](/a/2325).