# Why was "Check if a variable is one of a set of valid strings" put on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

They said:

> Questions must involve real code that you own or maintain. Pseudocode, hypothetical code, or stub code should be replaced by a concrete implementation. Questions seeking an explanation of someone else's code are also off-topic.

My approach (which someone edited to "one approach") is the *REAL CODE* that what we currently have in **PRODUCTION**.

Link to the question:
[Check if a variable is one of a set of valid strings](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/180867/103160)

I do not want my question to be "reopened". I just want to point out what happened and see if I'm wrong.

Comment: Have you copy-pasted the code directly from your code-base to Code Review Stack Exchange without any modifications at all?

Comment: Yes, the first one was a simple copy-paste. @SimonForsberg

Comment: Ops, the error message is different. I changed it because the original is in pt-br. But the code itself is the same.

Comment: And the variable name is `x` also in your actual code base?

Comment: It is `x`, yes, although that's not a good name at all.

Comment: Any thoughts? @SimonForsberg

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the snippet has so little context that it can't be true that you're interested in feedback on any/all aspects of the code; the snippet is basically a one-liner.

I would downvote (didn't), because I personally don't like that kind of A vs B questions with so little context there's not really anything else to say other than:

- hmm yeah yours looks good because XYZ
- hmm yeah the bottom snippet is better because XYZ
- hmm how about `this little one-liner snippet` instead, see how XYZ makes it better

Which *in my own personal opinion* isn't quite in the "spirit" of what this site is about.

See [*How to get the best value out of Code Review*](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/23788) for a comprehensive description of what's objectively better suited for this site.

---

That said, you have this:

```
throw new Error('OhGodWhy')
```

In real production code? Really? I don't blame the close-voters for deeming it "hypothetical" - the post raises most of the typical flags for that close reason, regardless of my own personal preference *against* A vs B questions.

---

Your post says:

> *We need to check if a given variable is either "get" or "post". If it's neither then I should throw an error.*

But we don't know why you need to do that - might be you deem it "irrelevant", but if we could see at least the whole function, or at least a bigger part of the bigger picture, then reviewers could possibly suggest ways to restructure things and perhaps completely avoid throwing that error - I don't know, but that's what reviewers like to do: look at *how you're solving a problem*, improve your implementation, and point out things that are wrong with the current one.

IMO the "relevant note" at the bottom of the post likely makes reviewers raise an eyebrow and spawns more questions than answers: if that code handles HTTP-GET and HTTP-POST, then what do CRUD operations UPDATE and DELETE have to do with it? What's that variable doing? What's its scope? Who's using it? Why?

If you don't want reviewers to question all the things and raise every flag they can, then you're not looking for a code review - you have a specific programming question (likely opinion-based), but you're not asking for a *peer review*.

And that's why I'm not going to single-handedly reopen your question: I agree with its closure.

Comment: 1 - My question wasn't only about A vs B, it was open to new suggestions as well (the two answers at the time present new ways of doing what I want to do). Anyway I agree there is little context and I should improve this.

Comment: 2 - the `"OhGodWhy"`is not in production. I used this in my question because the original message is in pt-br and I dont see why the error message is so relevant.

Comment: 3 - Same as 1...

Comment: The main problem that I see with the question is that it lacks sufficient context for us to give your proper advice. Code doesn't exist in a vacuum — it's used for something. I downvoted, having left the comment _"Please show the code in context: what happens after the validation succeeds or fails? Are you writing a webserver or what? Are these HTTP methods?"_  I could have closed the question as "Unclear what you are asking", but refrained. Now that five community members have closed it, though, I'm also not going to override their votes unless the necessary context is added.

Comment: I won't add anything to my question because I disagree on your edit. Your edit made me want to delete my question, but there was one answer there so I didn't delete it. @200_success

Comment: @Gabriel I don't see what's wrong with 200's edit, and FWIW you don't seem to be coming here with an open-minded attitude / genuinely wanting to improve your question. If you're looking for confrontation, you're in the wrong place. If all you wanted was to rant about your question being closed, you've done that, now move on: we told you what was wrong with your question, so either you fix your post and we'll reopen it, or you go on & everyone has a nice day. Holding a childish grudge over an edit (legit or not) isn't going to get you anywhere.

Comment: From this question: "I just want to point out what happened and see if I'm wrong.". And don't be rude. @Mat'sMug

Comment: Also I already understood why my question got closed and I kind of agree. That's all.

Answer (score -3):

the type of question that you are asking is not something that we really like to answer, because it involves your co-workers code, for which we don't know if you have permission to post his code.  ***you are posing his code versus your code***
and this causes conflicts with the purpose of the site.

This actually falls under the last statement in the close reason that was given

> Questions seeking an explanation of someone else's code are also off-topic.
>
> "Questions must involve real code that you own or maintain. Pseudocode, hypothetical code, or stub code should be replaced by a concrete implementation. ***Questions seeking an explanation of [someone else's code](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3654) are also off-topic."*** – Mast, Toby Speight, Marc-Andre

I suggest looking at the link

Comment: 1) it does not matter at all for you; 2) that's not the reason they left on the question.

Comment: it does, and it is.

Comment: About your edit: it is MY CODE. I showed my co-worker's suggestion just for the sake of completeness. It doesnt really matter.

Comment: When I click on your link, Chrome says "Attackers might be trying to steal your information".

Comment: the site must not be set up for https....I thought all the stack sites were set up for https

Comment: I disagree with this answer, I don't think that's the problem here at all.

Comment: Even if it is the code of a coworker, it is still code that the OP "maintains", so the potential legal issues is not a problem here.

Comment: "or code that you maintain." I do.

Comment: @SimonForsberg I don't think the employee owns the company. If they don't, then it's the _companies IP, and not the employees to give away_.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I still don't think the legal issues are the problem here. We've had plenty of work-code posted here before.

Comment: Even if it was the problem, there is nothing in the message to let me understand it. "Hey, you posted your co-worker's code and it can get us all in trouble, please remove it"