# Insecure links in custom close reasons should be HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons

In the comments on this meta [answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8522/71574), a person said:

> When I click on your link, Chrome says "Attackers might be trying to steal your information".

The link in question was from this quote:

> Questions seeking an explanation of someone else's code are also off-topic.
>
> "Questions must involve real code that you own or maintain. Pseudocode, hypothetical code, or stub code should be replaced by a concrete implementation. Questions seeking an explanation of [someone else's code](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3654) are also off-topic."

One problem should be obvious. The link goes to

```
http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3654
```

which is an HTTP link. It should almost certainly go to

```
https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3654
```

instead. Note that I made two changes:

1. Added the missing `s` to make `https`.
2. Swapped `codereview` and `meta`, as `meta.codereview` is the old form. They swapped so that they could use a `*.meta.stackexchange.com` certificate for every meta site.

I'm guessing that this isn't the only malformed link in the custom close reasons. They should probably all be verified.

Since the site has moved to HTTPS only, we should make our custom close reasons comply. I believe this is something that only a moderator can do.

Comment: The moderator GUI to change this leaves some things to be desired... I can't edit existing reasons that easily. I have asked the Stack Exchange team if they can do some search and replace of this. If they can't, then I guess we'll just have to do this manually. But I suspect this is a common thing on many sites.

Answer (score 5):

JNat, GraceNote and myself went through all the sites and edited these reasons to have valid meta links.

If you find one that we missed... Let me know & I'll fix that too.