# Could I have made my question "fast responsive navigation in CSS & jQuery" more attractive/better?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I would carefully like to ask, what (if at all) I could have done to make my question ["fast responsive navigation in CSS & jQuery"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180683/fast-responsive-navigation-in-css-jquery) more attractive and/or interesting for the community? Or is CSS and JavaScript in general not an interesting subject for this community?

Please be aware that I am not demanding an answer or stuff like that. I would just like to know if I could have done something better.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915)? Does it answer your question?

Comment: @Mast thanks for your comment. yes, I did read that before I asked my question. And I think I have followed most of the points mentioned in the "before you ask" section. The only think I can not do (or at least I dont know how) is to offering a bounty. The reason I asked this question here on meta is because I think I followed most of the tipps and that I just would like to know how I could make better/more suitable questions for this community

Comment: Just making sure, before the answers start pointing out the obvious :-)

Comment: lol, one good rule of thumb is to be careful about your spelling. transposing one little `o` with a `u` can make a perfectly innocent word look like a porno title.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. what? Did I make a spelling mistake? English is not my native language

Comment: your english is fine, i wouldnt have guessed it wasn't your native language.. that said, community has only one `U`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i for one, am a super lazy reader. i enjoy answering questions and solving problems but i don't always like to actually read the description, especially since so many people aren't native English speakers or are just bad at conveying ideas. often i'll skim the question and just go right to the code. i'm sure i'm not the only one. while this is entire my own fault and not yours, you will surely get more attention by making your questions as short and to the point as possible. that goes for teh code too. for example..

```
// add JS-classes into the HTML-Tag
$('html').addClass('js');
```

is it really necessary to comment this line of code? it took me longer to read the comment than it did to read the code and the code is basically as readable as natural english.

the first sentence is not relevant to the question and can safely be removed. congratulations and all, but we don't really need to know that it's your first project. honestly, you did a good a job so no one would have guessed that.

tldr: cut the fat in your question and you might get more responses. people are voluteering their time to help you for free so do whatever you can to make it easier for them. and on CR, if you don't get reviews, that's a good thing. that means there's nothing obvious that sticks out to readers as a problem. no one's going to leave an answer just to say you did a good job and there's nothing that can be improved.

Comment: thanks for your answer here too. Yes, I tend to write too much or too blooming? Mostly because I thought it would be rude if I just say things straight out. Maybe its a cultural thing? I mentioned that its my first project because I thought I could accuse pretty bad mistakes (or for something like "watch out for beginner misstakes", not to show off or something. I didn't know that getting no answers is a good sign, didnt know that answers saying  like its all good or uncommon here on CR. But if I know think about it, its a good way to handle it. Hope I didnt write too much for you

Comment: not at all.. I hope it was helpful :)

Comment: @undefined FYI... when writing comments in your code, it's almost always more useful to say *why* your code is doing what it's doing, rather than *what* it's doing. If you really have to explain *what* you are doing in a comment, then your code is probably too complex and you need to simplify it. However, knowing *why* the code was written is enormously helpful when debugging, because you can easily compare the programmer's intent against what was actually written.