# Why is my SPOJ question receiving downvotes?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, down-votes

[SPOJ- CPP: Gap in output](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203331/spoj-cpp-gap-in-output?noredirect=1#comment391915_203331)

What is the purpose of so many downvotes?

And what does it mean that the code should be "embedded directly"?

Answer (score 5):

> And what does it mean that the code should be "embedded directly"?

Both your code and the challenge description should be included in the question itself. Links rot and users aren't expected to follow any links to understand your question. The question should stand on itself. Neither were included in the first revision of the question.

On top of that, you ask the following:

> Check question link, why the gap in first output example?
>
> Same problem with my code.

As [indicated in the comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203331/spoj-cpp-gap-in-output#comment391915_203331), your question is ambiguous. There is no gap. Since the question appears to revolve around what that gap is and why it's there, are you even asking for a review.

That's two reasons why it got closed and attracted downvotes. Another reason for the downvotes is the apparent lack of effort invested and lack of quality of the question (especially the first revision).

The hovertext (what you get when your mouse hovers over the button) of the downvote button reads as follows:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)

When a question attracts multiple downvotes, there's a good chance one of those reasons is the cause.

To find out how to write a great question, please refer to [the relevant FAQ entry](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915).