# Question about "Polymorphic implementation of == with CRTP" on hold as off topic

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, closed-questions

I have a question about my Code Review Stack Exchange post: [Polymorphic implementation for == with CRTP](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/211445/polymorphic-implementation-for-with-crtp). It was put on hold as off topic stating (mainly) that the use case is theoretic or not explained.

---

Reading the [actual reasons](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) for off topic it doesn't seem that *theoretical usage* is a reason (as opposed to *pseudo-code or hypothetical*) -- as long as the presented code is real in the sense that it is working code with actual logic. Moreover there is even a tag for [`reinventing-the-wheel`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel) which is merely for theoretical code (code that you would probably not implement, as it is already written -- without requiring OPs to state the reason for reinventing-the-wheel -- it can be just for fun or for learning purposes).

By the way, after being put on hold, I added in a comment a *relevant use case*. But I do believe this is a valid and interesting C++ code for review anyhow (not being pseudo-code neither hypothetical).

So, do you think my [original post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/211445/polymorphic-implementation-for-with-crtp) it theoretical or maybe pseudo-code or hypothetical? Do you think it is off topic or maybe we are too quick with off topic?

Comment: On top of the close reason already provided, I think your question is lacking description. Please take a good look at [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915), update your question accordingly and it wouldn't surprise me if the question is quite salvageable.

Comment:  done -- question updated

Comment: Note that one of the contributing factors to the question being hypothetical, prior to your added explanation in Rev 5, is the fact that you used a "foobar" example with `class A` and `class B`. [Realistic concrete use cases are preferred](/help/how-to-ask), since they tend to give a clearer understanding of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 10):

> So, do you think my original post it theoretical? or maybe pseudo-code or hypothetical? do you think it is off topic?

Yes, and unclear, since it was lacking a description. In my opinion, it has been sufficiently improved since closure. So I've initiated the reopening process by casting the first vote.

Update: the question has been reopened.