# Non-HTTPS, wrong hostname links in sidebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, editor

The sidebar on `https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask` links to `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598`. Visiting this results in a redirect to the HTTPS version of that site. If HTTPS Everywhere is installed it also results in having to disable HTTPS Everywhere on that domain to load the redirect. It should instead link to `https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598` to avoid both these issues.

It also links to `http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436`. This is even worse, because after the HTTPS Everywhere prompt it redirects to `https://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436`, which has an invalid TLS configuration.

Here's the relevant extracts of the page (my line-breaks):

> ```
> If your code is incomplete or not working, you should ask for help
> <a href="http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598">on another site</a>.
>
> >We recommend reading our
> <a href="http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436">Guide to
> Asking Questions</a>.
> ```

Here's what I see in my browser:

[image: Security risk warning]

This link should instead be `https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436`.

PS/brag: I found these using the [Insecure Links Highlighter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/insecure-links-highlighter/) Firefox plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated the links to use HTTPS and the correct URL format for this meta site. Thanks for the heads-up!