# I don't understand the negative feedback on my question

Tags: support, specific-question, down-votes

I don't understand the negative feedback on my question [*Library to uniformly present runtime errors, exceptions, and login errors exceptions*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/255137)

Can anyone help me improve the post, without going out of context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have diamond mod privileges on this site, so I cannot see the full history of deleted comments, but if I recall correctly...

1. I found your question by searching for [php](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) questions (not the review queue).
2. I *think* I voted to close because the reviewable content needs to be embedded in the question.
3. I *think* I posted a comment to explicitly state that the question was off-topic for this reason.
4. The question was edited to included the relevant scripts in the question body.
5. I retracted my close vote.
6. I answered.
7. I edited the question title to remove the concern from the title and tried to uniquely describe what the script does.
8. I un-downvoted and upvoted the question.

The order of those events may be slightly off, but that's the general nature of it.

---

How do you prevent pile-on/snowballing downvotes in the future?

On CodeReview, there is a generally good vibe and steady trickle of upvotes for good posts (not all Stack Exchange sites enjoy such a "mature" collection of members).  To get on that "good" trajectory, follow this general guidance:

- take the tour
- educate yourself on what this SE community expects in a good question
- custom search for the highest voted questions with tags that your question might have and see if there are any standout features that you can adopt
- don't post your question until you have carefully proofread it so that it represents the best of your knowledge using the best grammar and formatting that you can craft.

When you do all of these things on CodeReview, you virtually assure that your question will be downvote-free.

Comment: Thanks guys, your contributions helped me a lot. Regards.

Answer (score 7):

Currently your question has a score of +0/-3, and there is one close vote against your question for our Authorship of Code close reason:

> **Authorship of code**: Since Code Review is a community where programmers improve their skills through peer review, we require that the code be [posted by an author or maintainer of the code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3654), that the code be [embedded directly](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653), and that the poster know why the code is written the way it is. 1

Your question was initially reviewed in the First Post queue. Then your question got a close vote review. Then you edited your question [14 hours ago to add the code into the question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/255137/2). You then got another close vote review.

---

Your question was off-topic and so people probably downvoted because of that. There have been three users that have interacted with your post, so getting 3 downvotes from that seems likely. It is also unlikely that the users have seen you make the edit to your post to undo the downvotes.

There could be other reasons why your question was downvoted - [the first revision of your answer wasn't great](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/255137/1). However your question seems fine now, from a skim read.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez That is fine. The reason your question was off-topic was because "the code be [embedded directly](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653)". But you added the code in the second revision, 14 hours ago. So AFAIK your question is on-topic.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Other than looking at how your post has been interacted with there's no way to know why you've had more votes. Other than [Tim Post lost his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397) again.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Possibly. Users that see this meta post who downvoted may see your updated question and undo the downvote. Or post a competing answer giving you a way to improve your question that I've failed to see.

Comment: ok thank you. i will wait what happend...

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Why would they do that? Please consider reading our [FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915), it has a lot of good points about improving the quality of your question and why things may not go as you thought they would.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez We don't have the ability to vote to delete your post until your post is closed. At this time only a moderator can delete your post. But I don't think a moderator will do that.

Comment: Thanks guys, your contributions helped me a lot. Regards.