# Asking questions on evolved code

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions

Sometimes I have a question on a specific class, piece of code, etc. I post the code, get some feedback and make changes as I see necessary. I then may add extra features to the code and it continues to evolve over time. Would it then be okay to ask a question on the same code base that has evolved based on feedback?

The question is basically: Is asking a question about a piece of code that has been changed based on a previous question wrong<sup>1</sup>?

---

<sub><sub>1. wrong isn't quite the right word but I couldn't think of a better one.</sub></sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We allow this, and have called them *iterative reviews*. Here's [the original meta post that asked if they're ok](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1065), and if you have any queries about the specifics then we have a tag on Meta for them: [iterative-review](/questions/tagged/iterative-review).