# Why is my second "Form maximum date/time from some digits" question being down voted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

My question here is getting down votes:

[Code Vita 7: Form the maximum possible date time in the MM/DD HH:MM format using any eight of twelve given single digits](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201380/code-vita-7-form-the-maximum-possible-date-time-in-the-mm-dd-hhmm-format-using)

which is a follow up to my previous question :

[Code Vita : Form the maximum possible time in the HH:MM:SS format using any six of nine given single digits](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200434/code-vita-form-the-maximum-possible-time-in-the-hhmmss-format-using-any-six)

The two questions are similar but quite different.

I dont understand why i am getting down votes.

Comment: Please see [How should I ask a follow-up question?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1066/31562)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first question received two answers, which said, in summary:

- "[Your code is repetitive and error-prone](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/200439/9357).  Here is a short algorithm that intelligently selects digits from the list, keeping in mind a few special limits."
- "[You could take advantage of Python's support for permutations and datetime](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/200466/9357).  Here is a short brute-force solution."

However, your second question took none of the advice from either answer.  It just uses the same error-prone strategy as your first try, and in fact it turned out to be buggy.  Is there much point to answering your second question, then, when the second challenge is more difficult than the first, the code is a duplicate of the first question in spirit, and it shows that you learned very little from the first question?

Comment: you are right i did make some changes but kept the approach the same. I was finding it difficult to understand the solns at that time since i am just an amateur in python programming. Can we use the two approaches to maximize the day too ?

Comment: Well, I write answers on this site to help other programmers learn, and it's disappointing when stuff I write goes over someone's head. I've added a few beginner tips in Rev 3 of my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: I've also posted a [working solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/201873/9357), based on a more generalizable algorithm, for solving these datetime maximization problems. Even though it's in C++, you may get some ideas by reading the comments on the `desc2iter` class and the nested for-loops in `max_datetime()`.

Answer (score 5):

I can think of one reason why I would downvote it.

It's always a good idea to summarize the changes you've implemented in the follow-up. This way people looking at it instantly know what to expect and how good or bad it is now and especially how many of the suggestions you ware able to incorporate into your code.

You could also explain why you didn't do certain things.

Without such a description people have to compare the code and this is a very time consuming task and probably nobody will be doing this.

---

In case of your question however it doesn't look as if was a follow-up at all. It's rather a completely different question so calling it a follow-up is very confusing.

---

Nevertheless if you have learned anything from the answers to the previous question and you were able to apply that knowledge, you can mention that too so that people know the code is getting better.

Comment: Also related: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1066/31562