# Why is my self answer being downvoted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, specific-answer, down-votes

I have shown that my code works. I have corrected people that they were wrong when they said my code does not create valid Sudoku. I'm awaiting valid reasons why my answer is being downvoted.

If you can debunk my algorithm formally, then I would appreciate it.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/221537/194047

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry that you're feeling that your answer is not appreciated, but looking through it, I can understand why it has been downvoted.... your answer does not review your code, it just presents an alternative solution without really indicating why the code in your answer is an improvement on your original code.

Code Review answers are expected to review the code, not just present alternative solutions...

If you want the code in your answer to be reviewed you should post it (with context) in a new post.

We have a special process for this: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765) and [How to post a follow-up question?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1065/31562)

Comment: Yeah, I need to keep practicing on writing answers.

Comment: I like to make sure my ground is firm, if I know I can stand it. I'm willing to accept corrections because I don't want to be arrogant. But, I don't need people saying something is wrong because other users may not fully understand the question or answer.

Comment: Another reason may be that you didn't give credit to whom it belongs my marking your answer as the answer.

Comment: @TravisWells You say you don't want to be arrogant, yet that's exactly how [this comment of yours](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220967/generate-n2-x-n2-sudoku-in-poly-time/221537#comment428363_221532) reads. The way you're perceived and the way you want to be perceived do not match yet.

Comment: @Mast If its correct, I wasn't sure how to say it any other way. If something is wrong, I say it direct and not with cues.

Comment: @Heslacher I have given thanks to the other answer. Is there a correct format of credit I should follow?

Comment: What I meant was what you did now: marking the answer as answer (grren checkmark).