# Collection of small unrelated methods

Tags: discussion

I have a file that contains a multitude of methods that are solutions to some common interview questions. *None* of these methods are related in any way, shape or form. I have been debating on the two possible ways of asking for review:

1. Posting the entire contents of the file and asking for review on each separate method
2. Posting each method as an individual question

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either is fine, but:

Posting too many unrelated functions in the same question may become a mess and hurt the quality of your question. Make sure you note which function is for which problem.

Posting too many questions in a short period of time *will* make sure the questions are less-well received. For one, it makes for poorer questions. Why bother reviewing someone's code if they've made the same mistake in the next 3 questions which are already posted as well?

A third approach you haven't mentioned yet, would be an option if you're not in a hurry. Post the first piece of code and use the feedback to improve the second *before* posting the second. Use the feedback of both to improve the third *before* posting the third. At that rate, your fourth or so question should contain some pretty decent code even if you start out with crap on the first (in theory).

Answer (score 6):

## Either is fine

1. Code is code, it doesn't matter if we don't think they relate, for all we know it could be a library of common things you're using.
2. This seems like a good idea too. This way you can easily and accurately explain each thing. But if you're posting a lot of questions in a short period of time you may not be well received.

Overall there's really no right way.
I would suggest posting the file in one question and if you feel any of the functions/classes were lacking in feedback to post [follow up questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1065).

But, you do you.