# Are 'follow up' questions on the same/similar code allowed?

Tags: support, asking-questions, duplicates

I had a code that I submitted here for review, and got a review. Good. But the implementation was primitive, and I have since written a new, more refined implementation, but the concept/intended purpose if the code is the same.

Should I create a new question with my new code for further review, or would that be considered a duplicate of my old question?

Comment: Related FAQs, especially the first two: [How to post a follow-up question?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1065/52915) [For an iterative review, is it okay to edit my own question to include revised code?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1763/52915) [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915)[Checklist for how to write a good Code Review question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1954/52915)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A new question with a link back to the old question for history is how we generally do follow up questions. The follow up questions are not considered duplicates of your old question. We prefer to see significant changes in the code but it isn't required.

How else are you going to learn from your previous code if you can't ask for a follow up review after you have modified the code?

Comment: How would I title such a question? Typically if I try to make a title too similar to an existing question the site will complain. And the title is supposed to be the intended purpose, which is the same, so...?

Comment: Try `Follow up to ...`. Should be ok, or Attempt 2.